# $A$ is homeomorphic to $A\times A$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

Is there any infinite topological space $A$ which is connected such that $A$ and $A\times A$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: Actually, being infinite is necessary, otherwise $|A| \neq | A \times A| ; |A|>1$ and the two cannot be homeomorphic by cardinality alone.

Comment: not true. A single element space is connected and its product with itself is homeomorphic.

Comment: Notice the $|A|>1$ included in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the easiest nice one is $\Bbb R^\mathbb{N}$ probably, in the product topology (product metric). If you want ugly spaces, the indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$ also works.

In fact, for *any* connected space $C$, the space $C^\mathbb{N}$ will be an example.

Comment: I think you can even generalize it further: For any connected space $C$ and any infinite set $I$, $C^I$ is an example.

Comment: @celtschk Sure, if you assume AC.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, one example would be $\mathbb{R^\infty}$ which squares to $\mathbb{R^{2\infty}}=\mathbb {R^\infty}$

Comment: How would you show the topologies are homeomorphic? And there are different infinities, e.g.$ \Bbb R^{\aleph_0}$ has a lower cardinal than $\Bbb R^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$

Comment: True, there are different infinities, however for any infinite cardinal $\aleph$ there is a bijection between any set with cardinality $\aleph$, and the disjoint union of two sets with cardinality $\aleph$; In other words, $\aleph = 2\aleph$. This bijection helps establish the homeomorphism.